# Split XML results from T-SQL into rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing

I have a query and I want to return XML and populate a datagrid.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    id, forename, surname
FROM 
    [datagen]
FOR XML path ('row')
```

The results I get are all on one line with no line breaks.

What do I need to do to break up the single line into multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *I need ... to break up the single line into multiple lines* means, that you want a single XML for each row, the next statement is a possible solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 x.XMLData
FROM [datagen] d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT d.id, d.forename, d.surname FOR XML path ('row')) x (XMLData)
```